# how to get logout url in Facebook C# SDK?

Tags: c#, .net, facebook-c#-sdk

I tried this:

```
 public string GetLogoutUrl()
        {
            return String.Format("https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com.br&access_token={0}", result.AccessToken);
        }
```

then:

```
webBrowser.Navigate(GetLogoutUrl());
```

Not worked. The user is redirected to facebook home page and not do logout.

how I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Also make sure the next url is belongs to your site url specified in the fb app settings.

```
next=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com.br
```

Answer (score 1):

Home page here I assume it as facebook's login page. If you are not logged in then it would redirect you to the login page.

If the Home page is the profile page then it would redirect you to the home page which is valid because facebook's logout is a form submit and you cannot do it using webBrowser.Navigate(url).

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with FB. Maybe this code can work for you

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

HtmlElement form = webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("logout_form");
HtmlElementCollection inputs = form.GetElementsByTagName("input");
foreach (HtmlElement input in inputs)
{
    if (input.GetAttribute("name") != "")
    {
        sb.Append(input.GetAttribute("name") + "=" + input.GetAttribute("value") + "&");
    }
}
sb.Length--;


WebClient www = new WebClient();
www.Headers["Cookie"] = webBrowser.Document.Cookie;
www.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";
www.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
www.Headers["Accept"] = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
webBrowser.DocumentText = www.UploadString("http://www.facebook.com/logout.php/", sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont u just issue a POST via HttpWebRequest? it seems more cleaner