# How to logout of facebook using FB C# SDK v5.3.2.0?

Tags: c#, facebook

i am stuck in the part where i have to log out the currently logged in user. can anyone please guide me about how to perform a logout since FacebookOAuthClient.GetLogoutURL() has been removed and marked obsolete.. any clue on hot to do this?

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8261568/how-to-get-logout-url-in-facebook-c-sharp-sdk/8262569#8262569

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a duplicate of:
[Cannot Logout of Facebook with Facebook C# SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394223/cannot-logout-of-facebook-with-facebook-c-sharp-sdk)
[Facebook logout C# SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023908/facebook-logout-c-sharp-sdk)

The option has been removed for a while and remains broken see [codeplex](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/discussions/272757). Logging out is not part of facebook's business model=P.

Comment: what do you mean its not a part of business model? ok now thats something strange.. any possible hacks to perform this in anyway through an httprequest or something? i mean there must be a way no?